# PostgreSQL - Database in Metabase does not contains any tables

Tags: postgresql, metabase

We have setup Metabase, PostgreSQL (RDS) in our AWS environment.

We added database in Metabase but do not see any tables inside

We also tried with click on sync tables/fields.

I am not sure what i need to do here to get tables into Metabase

Can anybody please help me here?

[image]

Comment: Creating a database does NOT generate any tables (well not unless you have them in a template database used). You need to populate the table definitions or import them.

Comment: Hello Belayer, Thanks for your reply, when you say "you need to populate the table definitions" how ?, thru sync? I am getting error "sync-and-analyze Database 9
BLOCKED" in log file.

Comment: I have no idea about how Metabase works, nor even what it is; never heard of it before. But I would begin with the [Metabase Documentation](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/). For myself I would just write DDL, ie Create Table...